# ntheorem not placing marker on next line

Tags: math-mode, ntheorem

Hi does anyone have a solution to this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3.cm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremsymbol{\enspace\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  Blah
  \begin{equation*}
    blah
  \end{equation*}
  which always hold a an normal almost contact 
  metric structure (see [1, Lemma~2.1]).
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]

as can be seen the box overflows the line instead of being moved to the next line. The text one the last line span the full text width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow (but discourage) a line break and allow the symbol to go flush right it seems to work better in this case:

```
\theoremsymbol{\nolinebreak[1]\hspace*{.5em plus 1fill}\ensuremath{\Box}}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. The flush right part should happen automatically in this case. Maybe I should write Wolfgang May.

Comment: It didn't flush right without the fill when I tried it. (but I didn't look at the documentation, just suggested the penalty/glue combination from first principles)